# How is Embyro "Thousands" of years old, if the destruction of old earth happened only 534 years ago?

Tags: cross-ange

Embyro self proclaimed to be thousands of years old. But he is shown in a flashback as a scientist in the 22nd century, and the destruction of old earth happened only 534 years ago.

How can he be that old?

Comment: Embryo could have been alive for thousands of years on old Earth, no? He's clearly not a regular human, after all.

Comment: He could be cain for all we know. But I was wondering, since he lives in a `non-deterministic universe` (as Tusk says in ep21) that he could be thousand of years old by living the same era more than once... but maybe it will be answered in the next chapters.

Comment: I thought that he was the one that destroyed the dragon's Earth by introducing the Rangamail there, which to me implies he had already crossed into the interdimentional rift, and so perhaps had hundreds of years to create the weapon.  So I don't think the mana earth was the first time he meddled with a universe.